# How to calculate frequency of element for two array in same document with arregation in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to calculate the frequency of tags from correctags and wrongtags from a different document on the basics of username there are multiple documents like below one
required data must have name of each student with there correct and wrong tags name with corresponding frequency of each different tag
I reach till here in my node js code,just getting correct tags correctly
Recently I started aggregation in MongoDB please guide me from where to study this

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'examid': new ObjectId('5f417a52ca1a8428a8eb5cdb')
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$correcttags'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'id': '$username', 
        'correctTag': '$correcttags', 
        'wrongTag': '$wrongtags'
      }, 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id.id', 
      'correct': {
        '$push': {
          'c': '$_id.correctTag', 
          'cf': '$count'
        }
      }, 
      'wrong': {
        '$push': {
          'w': '$_id.wrongTag', 
          'wf': '$count'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Required Information from each student

```
{
    "total":7,
    "math":0,
    "chemistry":0,
    "physics":7,
    "correcttags":[
        {
            "name":" Communications system",
            "fr":2
        }
    ],
    "wrongtags":[
        {
            "name":" Communications system",
            "fr":1
        }
    ],
    "username":"dhirav"
}
```

that's is my document for each student

```
   {
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"5f3e7b3958c08f1bd897cad9"
    },
    "total":7,
    "math":0,
    "chemistry":0,
    "physics":7,
    "correcttags":[
        " Communications system"," Communications system"           
    ],
    "wrongtags":[
        " Communications system",
                ],
    
    "examid":{
        "$oid":"5f3b61414d9b8a27ccdd3c6b"
    },
    "user":{
        "$oid":"5f189baf1e7fb81ce09fbb5f"
    },
    "username":"dhirav",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `$unwind` and `$group`,

- `$match` your conditons
- `$unwind` deconstruct `correcttags` array
- `$group` by `_id` and `correcttags` and do sum
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `correcttags` array, its done

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5f3e7b3958c08f1bd897cad9") } },
  { $unwind: "$correcttags" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id", correcttags: "$correcttags" },
      correcttags_fr: { $sum: 1 },
      total: { $first: "$total" },
      math: { $first: "$math" },
      chemistry: { $first: "chemistry" },
      physics: { $first: "$physics" },
      wrongtags: { $first: "$wrongtags" },
      username: { $first: "$username" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      correcttags: { $push: { name: "$_id.correcttags", fr: "$correcttags_fr" } },
      total: { $first: "$total" },
      math: { $first: "$math" },
      chemistry: { $first: "chemistry" },
      physics: { $first: "$physics" },
      wrongtags: { $first: "$wrongtags" },
      username: { $first: "$username" }
    }
  },
```

- repeat above same pipelines for `wrongtags` array

```
  { $unwind: "$wrongtags" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id", wrongtags: "$wrongtags" },
      wrongtags_fr: { $sum: 1 },
      total: { $first: "$total" },
      math: { $first: "$math" },
      chemistry: { $first: "chemistry" },
      physics: { $first: "$physics" },
      correcttags: { $first: "$correcttags" },
      username: { $first: "$username" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      wrongtags: { $push: { name: "$_id.wrongtags", fr: "$wrongtags_fr" } },
      total: { $first: "$total" },
      math: { $first: "$math" },
      chemistry: { $first: "chemistry" },
      physics: { $first: "$physics" },
      correcttags: { $first: "$correcttags" },
      username: { $first: "$username" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4pNEP1LnSfo)

Comment: can we combine both array so that we will tag name and correspondind correct or wrong frequency

Comment: i am not getting you can you give an example and update your question.

Comment: Communications system:{
                       "cf":1,
                       "wf":1
 }

Comment: basically I want to combine tags with object key as tag name combine frequency [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f3e7b3958c08f1bd897cad9"),
    "chemistry": "chemistry",
    "Tags": [
      Communications system:{
        "fr": 2,
        "Wf":1
      },
     a: {
        "fr": 1,
        " wf":1
      }
    ],
    "math": 0,
    "physics": 7,
    "total": 7,
    "username": "dhirav",
    
    ]
  }
]

Comment: look at this query its done https://mongoplayground.net/p/bzM7IbkljNe

Comment: U are really awesome I am trying to do it for hours thanks once again